# rails paperclip access image from another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

my app has an habtm relation b/w listings and categories. now from the categories index page, a user filters select box to view listings in the show page.

now i am not able to access images attached to listings in the category show page.

listing.rb

```
attr_accessible :placeholder, :categories_ids

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_attached_file :placeholder, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
                      :url => "/system/:hash.:extension",
                     :hash_secret => "longSecretString"
```

categories controller

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end

def show
  @categories = Category.find_by_sql ["select distinct l.* from listings l , categories c, categories_listings cl where c.id = cl.category_id and l.id = cl.listing_id and c.id in (?,?)" ,  params[:c][:id1] , params[:c][:id2]]
end
```

the sql just filters and displays the listings in show page where i can show its attributes, but cant access the placeholder. note the plural **@categories** in show

categories show page

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each_with_index do |c, index| %>
  <% if  index == 0 %>
    <li class="first"><%= c.place %></li>

    <%= image_tag c.placeholder.url(:thumb) %>

    <li><%= c.price %></li>

    <% else %>
    <li><%= c.place %></li>
    <li><%= c.price %></li>

    <%= image_tag c.placeholder.url(:thumb) %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
</ul>
```

[Access image from different view in a view with paperclip gem ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778108/access-image-from-different-view-in-a-view-with-paperclip-gem-ruby-on-rails)

this said to make the object plural and call a loop, wch shall allow to access the image.

it does not work in this case.

```
undefined method `placeholder' for #<Category:0x5c78640>
```

but the amazing thing is, placeholder will be displayed as an array of all images for all the listings if used as suggested in that stackoverflow, wch is, obviously, not the way i prefer. where's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Because category haven`t method placeholder, instead it have

Update:

```
@category.listings.each  do  |l| 
  l.placeholder
end
```

upd

Try just get category and then loop through its lisings

```
def show 
  @category = Category.find(params[:id]) #you get category and you able to loop throgh it listing array and get it placeholder
end
```

upd

```
@categoies.each_with_index  do  |c| 
  c.listings.each do |l|
    l.placeholder
  end
end
```

upd2:

```
@categoies.each_with_index  do  |c,i| 
  c.listings.each do |l|
    image_tag l.placeholder.url(:thumb)
  end
end
```

Comment: it wont work. the @category object stores listings by sql. i cant use .listings in the do loop. it throws up nomethod error.

Comment: all attributes of listings can be accessed in its present form. but cant access placeholder. it is a column in listings. but y?

Comment: As I understand in show action you want do display all listing that belongs to category and listings placeholder. Am I wright?

Comment: yup. that is wat i am trying. i can display all listings with its attributes but not the placeholder

Comment: Why won't you just use @category = Category.find(params[:id])?

Comment: coz der are multiple select box to filter the listings, based on categories, price, etc. thats y the sql. wat i hv put here is based on two category select boxes. i cannot understand one thing, since listings has a column named placeholder, y is it not showing up, but rest of the attributes are?

Comment: didnt get u. last variant??

Comment: hey i got two select box to send the params. not running like this - @category = Category.find([params[:name][:id],params[:name][:id]]).

Comment: hey got that fixed. but now all images for all listing is shown. not able to get it individually for each instance of listing.

Comment: hey, but there are other issues like i have to use other parameters of form to sort the listings. now i get the listing based on category. i, also, have to sort on other parameters of listings. how will i do that.