# rails paperclip unable to access image from another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

my app has an habtm relation b/w listings and categories. now from the categories index page, a user filters select box to view listings in the show page.

now i am not able to access images attached to listings in the category show page.

listing.rb

```
attr_accessible :placeholder, :categories_ids

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_attached_file :placeholder, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
                      :url => "/system/:hash.:extension",
                     :hash_secret => "longSecretString"
```

categories controller

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end

def show
  @categories = Category.find_by_sql ["select distinct l.* from listings l , categories c, categories_listings cl where c.id = cl.category_id and l.id = cl.listing_id and c.id in (?,?)" ,  params[:c][:id1] , params[:c][:id2]]
end
```

the sql just filters and displays the listings in show page where i can show its attributes, but cant access the placeholder. note the plural @categories in show

categories show page

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each_with_index do |c, index| %>
  <% if  index == 0 %>
    <li class="first"><%= c.place %></li>

    <%= image_tag c.placeholder.url(:thumb) %>

    <li><%= c.price %></li>

    <% else %>
    <li><%= c.place %></li>
    <li><%= c.price %></li>

    <%= image_tag c.placeholder.url(:thumb) %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
</ul>
```

[Access image from different view in a view with paperclip gem ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778108/access-image-from-different-view-in-a-view-with-paperclip-gem-ruby-on-rails)

this said to make the object plural and call a loop, wch shall allow to access the image.

it does not work in this case.

```
undefined method `placeholder' for #<Category:0x5c78640>
```

but the amazing thing is, placeholder will be displayed as an array of all images for all the listings if used as suggested in that stackoverflow, wch is, obviously, not the way i prefer. where's the issue? what am i missing?

Comment: Do you have the relevant `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship set up in the category.rb model?

Comment: everything is der. i can show listings in the category show page with all its attributes but not the placeholder image.

Comment: And you've got the placeholder image columns in the categories db?

Comment: no. how am i suppose to set that up and link it to the listing model. also, paperclip generates 4 columns based on placeholder. how will it work, by calling only placeholder.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've confused you! What I really meant was "have you set up the Paperclip columns as you require them, and do they work in standard situations?"

Comment: yes i have. it shows up perfectly in the listings index and show page. but i believe there exits some kind of hack to make it work in another model-view page. can u help sort that out.

Comment: I can certainly help, but I'd stay clear of "hacking" anything together! Have you created the HABTM join model?

Comment: as i said, everything works perfectly. i can even perform a filter search from the category index page and have the results shown in the show page with all the listings attributes, but not the placeholder wch is also a column in the listings model, made exactly how the paperclip github page said.

Comment: Hmmmmm - are you not seeing any errors in your logs or anything?

Comment: undefined method `placeholder' for #<Category:0x5c78640>

Comment: Okay, can you post your full code for the following files: listing.rb, category.rb, categories_controller.rb, listings_controller.rb ? I would ask to go into a chat, but you don't have enough reputation yet :(

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kpcvG01q

Comment: Thank you!! Let me check this out

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at your code, the immediate issue I can see is that `placeholder` is part of the `listing.rb` model, not `category.rb`

---

**ActiveRecord Objects**

When you call an ActiveRecord object (e.g `@categories = Category.all`), the ActiveRecord object is created on the `Category` model, which means any dependencies from that will have to be accessed like an array -> `@categories.listings`

The associations of these records are created with the various `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations you created in your models, which seem to be working correctly

So my recommendation is to call listings as a dependency of Category, like this:

```
<%= image_tag c.listings.first.placeholder.url(:thumb) %>
```

---

**Update**

To show all the images for the listings, you will have to just do an `.each` loop, like this:

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each_with_index do |c, index| %>
  <% if  index == 0 %>
        <li class="first"><%= c.place %></li>

        <% c.listings.each do |listing| %>
            <%= image_tag listing.placeholder.url(:thumb) %> 
        <% end %>

        <li><%= c.price %></li>
    <% else %>
        <li><%= c.place %></li>
        <li><%= c.price %></li>

        <% c.listings.each do |listing| %>
            <%= image_tag listing.placeholder.url(:thumb) %> 
        <% end %>

    <% end %>

  <% end %>
</ul>
```

---

**ActiveRecord & Paperclip**

I think the conclusion is this:

Your SQL query is bringing back the "pure data" from your listings database. That's fine, but you want to use Paperclip's `.url` function, which only fires with `ActiveRecord` (it creates an image object & attaches to the ActiveRecord object)

Your listings db has these columns:

- placeholder_file_name
- placeholder_content_type
- placeholder_file_size
- placeholder_updated_at

These cannot create an image output for you, as the image file is stored in a different path to the `placeholder_file_name`

When you use Paperclip, it takes the data stored in these columns & creates an ActiveRecord image object, which you can then call by using `c.listings.first.placeholder.url`. Notice how the `placeholder` column is not in the database at all; meaning Paperclip needs to be called by `ActiveRecord` before you can use its functionality

You *could* use a query like this (this is a complete stab in the dark to be honest, but hope it gives you more insight):

```
@categories = Category.joins(:listings).where(:id => [params[:c][:id1],params[:c][:id2]])
```

Comment: okay that shows the first instance for the placeholder. since, result will show many listings, it would not work for rest of the listings. i used the sql coz user can filter listings based on their choice. i believe, as u suggest, the issue may be with the sql. now going forward, how am i suppose to make it work??

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply! My fix works to show only one image? That's good because it means we're on the right track. It also means that we might not have to change your SQL.... let me make an edit

Comment: now it is showing all the images stored for each listing. okay wat i meant was to show placeholder image associated for each instance of the listing. for eg, if result show 2 listing a and b, so image associated for "a" along with its other attributes, then image associated for "b" along with its other attributes. like that.

Comment: === Having looked at your code, the immediate issue I can see is that  placeholder is part of the listing.rb model, not category.rb ==== but i guess the sql stores all attributes of listings in the @category object, thats y i am able to simply call c.price, c.place easily. but y not placeholder.

Comment: Because placeholder is a part of the `Listing` model, not `Category` model. The way ActiveRecord works is to call its associative records as array-like dependent objects, which need to be called before you can output any referenced objects, like `@categories.listings.placeholder.url`

Comment: Although your 2nd-to-last comment was slightly confusing, how do you define the associative images? For example, you say that listing A needs to have image A, etc; how do you define those associations?

Comment: b/w === was ur comment.

Comment: what do you mean by b/w?

Comment: if i am able to access all attributes of listings in @category, by calling c.place, c.price and not c.listings.place and c.listings.price, so i expected it shud be called as <%= image_tag c.placeholder.url(:thumb) %>

Comment: between. i quoted the first line of the answer dat u had written.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Looking at it, it looks like your SQL query _could_ be the problem, because it will call the hard data from the listings table, which I don't think will come through ActiveRecord's associations structure. Now, this is okay... but what you're trying to do is access the placeholder through a paperclip function. Paperclip works in the background with ActiveRecord to create a file object & attach it to the ActiveRecord request (as `placeholder` in your case). I think this means that if you're receiving the hard data, you can't use the `placeholder.url` command

Comment: To test this, you should replace: `<% c.listings.each do |listing| %>
            <%= image_tag listing.placeholder.url(:thumb) %> 
        <% end %>` with this: `<%= c.placeholder_file_name %>`

Comment: i really appreciate the time u are taking to help resolve the issue. thnx ;)

Comment: No problem - it helps me improve! You should run the test I made, because I think your problem is that your SQL is preventing you from using the ActiveRecord data, and corresponding paperclip functions

Comment: i had tried that earlier. that way it worked, but including it in the image tag, showed no image.

Comment: I can construct a better SQL query for you if you tell me what you want to appear in your view? When you say "associated image", you mean you just want to get Paperclip to show the image contained in the listing row? I.E each listing just has one placeholder image?

Comment: yup this is wat i am attempting to do. to show the image i had attached to each individual listing.

Comment: i included the complete form coz i am not pretty sure if i will be able to extend ur sql further to my requirements

Comment: I could definitely get it working if I had your system in front of me, because I like to keep trying until it works. It's hard to gauge how a query will run whilst not being able to test :(

Comment: can u tell me just the general guidelines so that i can give a try

Comment: nope, the sql u wrote does not work.  any alternate approach u can suggest wch can work for the image?

Comment: I think the code I wrote will yield what you need, but we need to work out what goes in the `.where` tag

Comment: What do you mean by "on place"?

Comment: Btw it might be worth asking a new question about how to make your SQL query into an ActiveRecord-friendly one? :) We've found the issue, we just need a workable solution

Comment: c.place, c.price. on that it throws no method error now. it aint recognising anything now

Comment: It won't, because our new query doesn't fetch the required data. You'll be better asking a new question specifically about how to make your SQL query into an ActiveRecord-friendly one, so you can call Paperclip's functions :)

Comment: No probs! Let me know the new question & I'll add an answer if I get any ideas from the other guys